# iCloud Enable/Disable using toggle from application side

Tags: iphone, core-data, icloud

I want to make enable/disable sync my core data with iCloud. Is it good way to do?
Can you share logic what should i have to do?
Here i am trying to remove and reinsert persistence store again when switch enable/disable.

Thanks,